# how to reset expectations on a mocked class method?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

Sorry if this is plain simple. i am new to ruby as well as rspec and it seems rspec is a very 'obscure' world (esp when coming from a .net background).

In my 'spec', i have:

```
before(:each) do
    expect(File).to receive(:exist?).with("dummy.yaml").and_return (true)
end
```

This works fine for all my 'examples', except one where i want it to return false.

```
expect(File).to receive(:exist?).with("non_existent.yaml").and_return (false)
```

This obviously fails my test because although "non_existent.yaml" expectation was met, the "dummy.yaml" was not:

```
(<File (class)>).exist?("dummy.yaml")
       expected: 1 time with arguments: ("dummy.yaml")
       received: 0 times
```

So how can i do a 'Reset' on 'File.exist?' (a class method mock) before i setup the new expectation for it? (... "non_existent.yaml"..)

i googled and it yielded:

```
RSpec::Mocks.proxy_for(your_object).reset
```

but this gives me:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `proxy_for' for RSpec::Mocks:Module
```

Comment: You should never use `expect to receive` in `before` block. This belong to tests.

Comment: try `RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(your_object).reset`

Comment: BroiSatse: i assumed 'before' is akin to '[Setup]' (nUnit: .net): setups that are common among different tests should be placed here, helps keep tests DRY and flexible to changes? Or does RSpec uses some other terminology for what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: @UriAgassi Thank You, that worked! Would You please post it as an answer so that i can accept it. Also, i wonder why such a tedious syntax for simply resetting a mock? shouldn't it be straight-forward function call? or am i trying RSpec to behave like nUnit (and other testing frameworks)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could not find anywhere in the documentation that this is how you should do it, and past behaviors goes to show that this solution might also change in the future, but apparently this is how you can currently do it:

```
RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(your_object).reset
```

I would follow @BroiSatse's remark, though, and think about re-designing the tests, aiming to move the expectation from the `before` block. The `before` block is meant for setup, as you say, and the setup is a very weird place to put expectations.

I'm not sure how you came to this design, but I can suggest two possible alternatives:

- If the test is trivial, and will work anyway, you should create one test with this explicit expectation, while stubbing it for the other tests:

  ```
  before(:each) do
    allow(File).to receive(:exist?).with("dummy.yaml").and_return (true)
  end

  it "asks if file exists" do
    expect(File).to receive(:exist?).with("dummy.yaml").and_return (true)
    # do the test...
  end
  ```
- If the expectation should run for every test, since what changes in each scenario is the *context*, you should consider using [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

  ```
  shared_examples "looking for dummy.yaml" do 
    it "asks if file exists" do
      expect(File).to receive(:exist?).with("dummy.yaml").and_return (true)
      # do the test...
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like "looking for dummy.yaml" do 
    let(:scenario) { "something which sets the context"}
  end
  ```

You might also want to [ask myron](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/new) if there is a more recommended/documented solution to reset mocked objects...

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me to unmock a specific method from a class:

```
mock = RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(MyClass)
mock.instance_variable_get(:@method_doubles)[:my_method].reset
```

Note: Same logic of 
`RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(MyClass).reset` which resets all methods

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@Uri Agassi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308667/how-to-reset-expectations-on-a-mocked-class-method/25316668#25316668) and as I [answered on another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709692/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-a-method-is-stubbed-with-rspec/58946308#58946308), I found that I could use `RSpec::Mocks.space.registered?` to check if a method was a mock, and `RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(my_mocked_var).reset` to reset it's value.

Here is [the example I included in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709692/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-a-method-is-stubbed-with-rspec/58946308#58946308):

> ### Example: Resetting a mocked value
>
> For example, if we wanted to `reset` this mock back to it's unmocked
>   default value, we can use the `RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for` helper to
>   find our mock, then `reset` it:
>
> ```
> # when
> #   Rails.configuration.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection == false
> # and
> #   allow(Rails.configuration.action_controller).to receive(:allow_forgery_protection).and_return(true)
>
> RSpec::Mocks.space.registered?(Rails.configuration.action_controller)
> # => true
>
> Rails.configuration.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection
> # => true
>
> RSpec::Mocks.space.proxy_for(Rails.configuration.action_controller).reset
>
> Rails.configuration.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection
> # => false
> ```
>
> Notice however that the even though the mock value has been reset, the
>   mock remains `registered?`:
>
> ```
> RSpec::Mocks.space.registered?(Rails.configuration.action_controller)
> # => true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When using "expect_any_instance" I had success using the following method to change the mock (e.g. our example: Putting out a Twitter post and returning a different tweet id)

```rb
expect_any_instance_of(Twitter::REST::Client).to receive(:update).and_return(Hashie::Mash.new(id: "12"))
# post tweet

RSpec::Mocks.space.verify_all
RSpec::Mocks.space.reset_all

expect_any_instance_of(Twitter::REST::Client).to receive(:update).and_return(Hashie::Mash.new(id: "12346"))
# post another tweet
```